# Thickbox not opening with anchor tags generated at runtime

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I am having an issue opening a thick-box with anchor tags appended to a div at runtime.The anchor tag contains the thick-box css and the href,that is required to open up a thickbox.However,its not opening up the required page in a thickbox.
All it does is,open up the page in a new page. However,when i crate a hard coded anchor with the required thickbox stuff,it opens up fine.The only issue is ,it doesn't do the same when it is generated at runtime .

I am using Jquery to append the anchor tags.

**Doesn't Jquery understand anchor tags with thickbox property append at runtime ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to my question

Thick-box has it own limitation.
**In case of thickbox, the events are attached on page load.**
So,if we are generating thick-box anchor tags at runtime,thickbox doesn't load itself with the anchor tags.

So,the solution is after generating the runtime anchor tag with thicbox detailed stuff,you would need to reload thickbox.
This is achieved by writing the simple piece of code stated below,after generating your run-time anchor tags.

```
tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');
```

The above piece of code reloads the thickbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're setting the action of the click event by using

```
$('.className').click(...);
```

or

```
$('.className').bind('click', ...);
```

These bindings don't get reset when you add new tags to the DOM at runtime.  You need to use:

```
$('.className').live('click', ...);
```